# To search from the api and print the data separately in a table

Tags: reactjs

1. - #### const [userID, setUserId] = useState("");

     let userid = ""

     axios
     .get('url').then((process) => {

     ```
            const proces = process.data;

            proces.map((item) =\> {

                if (item.fulname === fulname) {

                    userID += (\`${item.id}\\n\\n\`)

                    setUserId(userid)})

                \<div\>

                    {userID}

                \</div\>
     ```

`How to print, whatever I did, it doesn't work, please guide me`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I'm considering your userid is in data only one time.
There are a lot of syntax errors in this code. JavaScript is case sensitive so write code carefully or you can use Syntax autocomplete extensions to avoid these mistakes.

```
var userid = ""
axios.get('url').then((process) => {
    const proces = process.data;
    proces.map((item) => {
       if (item.fulname === fulname) {
           userid += (`${item.id}\\n\\n`);
           setUserId(userid);
       })
    })
})
   
return(<div>{userID}</div>)
```